# Values of $x$ satisfying $\lfloor x\rfloor + 3\{x\} > 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Which values of $x$ satisfy $\lfloor x\rfloor + 3\{x\} > 1$?

$\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer function and $\{\cdot\}$ denotes the fractional part function.

Comment: What have you done so far? where are you stuck?

Comment: I am just doing trial method I want to know a General method

Comment: I think it would be done by trial method only

Comment: Take $n \leq x <n+1$ where $n$ is an integer and see what it means for $[x]+3{x}$ to be greater than  $1$.

Comment: Any thing bigger than $1$ works clearly. But I don't get it : do you want all values of $x$ for which this is true? Also, the fractional part of $-0.01$ is $.01$, keep that in mind.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг:  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Notation) disagrees with you.  It says the fractional part of $-2.7$ is $0.3$, with the fractional part being the distance down to the next integer.  It says some computer languages differ and follow the convention you cite.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг The fractional part of $-0.01$ is $0.99$.  $0 \le \{ x\} < 1$ and $[x] \le x = [x] + \{x\} < [x] + 1$ so as $-1 < -0.01 < 0$ we know $[-0.01] = -1$ and as $-0.01 = -1 + 0.99$ we know $\{0.01\} = 0.99$.

Comment: @fleablood and Ross, I should have checked that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If $\frac 23 < \{x\} < 1$ then $2 \le 3\{x\} < 3$ and $[x]+2 < [x] + 3\{x\} < [x] + 3$  so  if $[x] \le -2$ this fails but if $[x] \ge -1$ this succeeds.

If $\{x\} =\frac 23$ then $\{x\} = 2$ and $[x] + 3\{x\} = [x]+2 >1$ so if $[x] \le -2$ this fails, and if $x = -1$ this fails (we have $[x]+3\{x\} = 1\not > 1$). But if $x \ge 0$ it succeeds.

If $\frac 13 < \{x\} < 1$ then $1 \le 3\{x\} < 2$ and $[x]+1 < [x] +3\{x\} < [x]+2$. so if $[x]\le -1$ then this fails but if $[x] \ge 0$ this succeeds.

If $\{x\} =\frac 13$ then $[x]+3\{x\} = [x]+1 > 1$ so if $[x]\le 0$ this fails but succeeds if $[x] \ge 1$

If $0 < \{x\} < \frac 13$ then $0 < 3\{x\} < 1$ and $[x] < [x] + 3\{x\} < [x]+ 1$ so this fails if $[x]\le 0$ but succeeds if $[x] \ge 1$.

If $\{x\} 0=$ then $[x]+3\{x\} = [x]$ and this succeeds if $[x] > 1$ but fails if $[x] \le 1$.

....

So this fails if $x < -1$ (because the $[x]\le -2$).

If $-1 \le x < 0$ then this succeeds if $\frac 23< \{x\} < 1$, but fails other wise.  So if $x\le -\frac 13$ we have failure but if $-\frac 13< x < 0$ we have success.

If $0 \le x < 1$ we have success if $\frac 13 < \{x\} < 1$, but fail otherwise.  So if $\frac 13 < x< 1$ we have success but $0\le x \le \frac 13$ wil have failure.

If $1 \le x $ then we have failure if $x=1$ but success other wise.

So the solution set is $(-\frac 13,0)\cup (\frac 13,1)\cup (1,\infty)$.

Comment: +1 Interesting. I checked it with Mathematica using FractionalPart and it came out wrong. Looking a little harder (since I know your answers are rarely wrong) I found Mathematica uses a non-standard definition for FractionalPart!

Comment: I'm not at all above an arithmetic error.  So I wouldn't be surprised if turned something completely around.  But if mathematica uses.  a definition that $\{x\} = \{|x|\}$ (so that $\{-1.01\} = -0.01$ rather than $\{-1.01\} = 0.99$ I wouldn't be surprised either.